# What does the "Duplicate the top item on the stack" mean in Whitespace language?

Tags: esoteric-languages, whitespace-language

I am trying to implement a Whitespace interpreter for fun, currently I am following [this tutorial](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.html) to learn its syntax.

The syntax looks easy, but I don't understand what "Duplicate the top item on the stack" mean. What does that mean? does it mean to get the value of stack top and save it into a special register?

Answer (score 8):

It means take the value on top of the stack, without popping it, and push a second copy of the exact same thing.

Now there are 2 of whatever it was.

The exact way to implement will depend upon what functions you have available to manipulate your stack. If you have just *push* and *pop*, then you could do it like this:

```
x = pop();
push(x);
push(x);
```

If you have a *top* function which can get the top element without popping it, you could do:

```
x = top();
push(x);
```

Or even:

```
push(top());
```

which reads as nice as pseudocode. :)